# Converting the HTML part of the current Facebook button into the Jade Template Language?

Tags: html, pug

This is the code for the Facebook like button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=101562769948573";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://foodjing.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I would like to write that in Jade (because my index is a jade file).
How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into jade documentation .https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

I would suggest you the following:

```
div#fb-root
script
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=101562769948573";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

div.fb-like(data-href="http://foodjing.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true")
```

Answer (score 4):

Late reply but you may want to check
http://html2jade.org/